# SharePoint 2013 App - CRUD operation

Tags: c#, sql, sharepoint

I am new to Sharepoint 2013 app with external content. I can pull the data from SQL and can populate in the App page. However I try to add new data, I am received following error message

---

**Message from webpage**

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"An entry without a type name was found, but no expected type was specified. To allow entries without type information, the expected type must also be specified when the model is specified.\"}}}","status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}
```

### OK

I have used following code

```
create: function (dname, description) {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl +
                    "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('tblDomain_SP')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify({'DomainName':dname,'Description':description}),
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function () {
            REST.DomainFormFiller.clear();
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        }

    });

}
```

could you please help me to insert data to sql table?

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> An entry without a type name was found, but no expected type was
>   specified. To allow entries without type information, the expected
>   type must also be specified when the model is specified

occurs due to missing `Type` attribute  in List Item entry.

### List Item Types

To create list items you will need to include the list item type. This is a string automatically created by SharePoint when the list is first created. Two possible ways to obtain this are:

- Perform a read operation on the list and locate the type within the
  returned set of elements. In JSON format the type can be found within
  the `__metadata` attribute of all of the returned list items.
- You can attempt to generate the value from the list name. In general
  list item types follow the convention `SP.Data.ListNameListItem` (e.g.
  list name is `Test`, list item type is `SP.Data.TestListItem`). However
  this is not always the case. For example SharePoint automatically
  capitalises the first letter of the list name (e.g. list name `test`
  list item type is `SP.Data.TestListItem`).

### Solution

The following code snippet shows how to generate the List Item Type based on the list name:

```
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return"SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1) + "ListItem";
}
```

Then you need to replace the line:

```
data: JSON.stringify({'DomainName':dname,'Description':description}),
```

with this one:

```
data: JSON.stringify({'DomainName':dname,'Description':description,"__metadata": { "type": GetItemTypeForListName('tblDomain_SP') }}),
```

### References

[Manipulating list items in SharePoint Hosted Apps using the REST API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2013/02/22/manipulating-list-items-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-using-the-rest-api.aspx)